# Prototype post data not going through to asp.net mvc Actionrequest

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, prototypejs

Need assistance please. (More confused than anything really)

I've got ASP.NET mvc controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Dashboard(string Whatever)
    {
        //Save name to database
        System.IO.StreamWriter swLogFile = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\test.txt", true);
        swLogFile.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + ":" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Millisecond) + " - " + Whatever);
        swLogFile.Close();

        return Content("success");
    }
```

Simply i want to capture what is passed from (string Whatever) when data is passed via prototype on my view form.

```
new Ajax.Request(this.options.saveurl,
    {method:'post', Whatever:"Scott", onComplete:function(t) 
    {$('data').update(t.responseText + $('data').innerHTML);
    } });
```

However when this executes the 'Whatever' is always null.  Am i missing something.  If i use jQuery i get no problems.
(my jQuery example).

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.post("/Home/Dashboard/Dashboardsave", { Whatever: "Scotta" }, function(data) { alert(data); });
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

Scotty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `parameters` property:

```
new Ajax.Request(this.options.saveurl, {
    method: 'post', 
    parameters: { Whatever: 'Scott' },
    onComplete: function(t) {
        $('data').update(t.responseText + $('data').innerHTML);
    } 
});
```